# Problema com injeção de dependência no demoiselle-report

Tags: demoiselle, jasper-reports

Gostaria de colocar um relatório em um projeto que estou trabalhando, e resolvi usar o o componente que próprio demoiselle fornece, o **demoiselle-report**. Porém após implementar o mesmo e testar, ele retorna uma exception. Pelo que verifiquei o problema está acontecendo ao realizar a injeção de dependência na Classe Report. Pesquisei na lista de usuários, e vi que muitas pessoas tiveram problemas semelhantes e que o mesmo estava relacionado a versão do demoiselle, acredito que o meu possa ser isso também, pois estou utilizando a última versão do framework. Abaixo vou descrever as implementações que fiz em meu projeto para usar o componente.

**Versões**

demoiselle 2.5.0

demoiselle-report 2.2.0

Primeiro inseri a dependência do componente no pom do meu projeto

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-report</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Depois criei um relatório simples, e coloquei o `.jasper` do mesmo no diretório sugerido na documentação

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feito isso, fui no managed bean criei o objeto report e o método que será chamado pelo JSF (Retirei a exception "JRException", pois o eclipse informava que não era necessária a mesma)

```
@NextView("/private/documento_manutencao_list.jsf")
@ViewController
public class DocumentoManutencaoListMB extends GenericListPageBean<Documento, String, DocumentoBC> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private DocumentoBC documentoBC;

    @Inject
    private Report report;

    @Inject
    private FileRenderer renderer;

    public String showReport() {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        try {
            byte[] buffer = this.report.export(documentoBC.findAll(), param, Type.PDF);
            this.renderer.render(buffer, FileRenderer.ContentType.PDF, "relatorio.pdf");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Faces.addMessage(e);
        }
        return getNextView();
    }

    // JRException não foi usado pois o eclipse retorna que é um código inacessível.
    // Unreachable catch block for JRException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body
```

E no JSF coloquei uma chamada no botão, conforme está descrito na documentação

```
 <p:commandButton process="listaDocsEmissaoPropria" icon="ui-icon-print" value="Imprimir" action="#{documentoManutencaoListMB.showReport}" />
```

Após realizar todos esses procedimentos, executo a aplicação e quando ele acessa a página do Managed bean o mesmo retorna a Exception abaixo:

> 09:37:52,643 GRAVE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Error Rendering View[/private/index.xhtml]: javax.el.ELException: /private/documento_manutencao_list.xhtml @59,68 value="#{documentoManutencaoListMB.listaDocTable}": javax.enterprise.inject.CreationException
>
> 09:37:52,706 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/DJCloud-seguranca].[Faces Servlet]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.internal.producer.LoggerProducer.create(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/slf4j/Logger;

Link para baixar exception completa retornada:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/xxuuza4j7scb2wc/exception_retornada.txt?dl=0

Realizei vários testes e vi que que deixando apenas a declaração do objeto report junto com a injeção de dependência, o erro ainda persiste, então creio que seja um erro no momento de realizar a injeção de dependência.

```
@Inject
private Report report;
```

Se alguém já tiver passado pelo mesmo problema, ou possa ajudar, ficarei agradecido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está parecendo o mesmo problema relatado no tracker do projeto: https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/browse/RPT-7

Estamos testando a correção na versão 2.2.1-SNAPSHOT.

Para isso, verifique se no POM.XML está configurado o repositório do Demoiselle.
Ex: https://github.com/demoiselle/example/blob/master/estacionamentov25X/pom.xml

Veja se é isso mesmo, ou se trata-se de outro problema.